# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'setRestaurants')

Tags: reactjs

I'm working on a project where I am trying to fetch a list of restaurants from a database and display them on the screen.

When I run the code below I get this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'setRestaurants')
> at CustomerDashPage.js:39
> at async fetchList (CustomerDashPage.js:39)
> at async getList (CustomerDashPage.js:32)

I know the fetch from the database works as I can console.log restaurants after I get them and all the tags from the database are the same as what is initially in the useState.

```
   
    const [restaurants, setRestaurants] = useState([
        {
            Restaurant_id: "R763567026",
            Restaurant_menuID: 0,
            Restaurant_name: "Boston Pizza",
            Restaurant_address: "271 Blackmarsh Rd",
            Restaurant_postal: "P1Z 7A5",
            Restaurant_username: "firstrest",
            Restaurant_orders: ["O415052628", "O321764897", "O252073901", "O724516036"],
            Restaurant_menuID: "M859068353",
            Restaurant_category: "Japanese",
            Restaurant_availability: true,
            Restaurant_openHour: "11h00",
            Restaurant_closeHour: "22h00",
        },
    ]);

    useEffect(() => {

        const getList = async () => {
            const fetchRest = await fetchList('R763567026');
        }
        getList();
    }, [])

    const fetchList = async (id) => {
        try {
            const resp = await fetch("/restaurant/id/" + id)
                .then((resp) => resp.json())
                .then(data => this.setRestaurants(data)).then(console.log(restaurants))
                .catch(err => console.log(err));
        }
        catch (err) {
            throw err;
            console.log(err);
        }
        return true;
    }

  //Controls what happens when a restaurant is selected.
    const selectRestaurant = async (id) => {
        console.log(id);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <Header />
            <RestaurantList
                itemList={restaurants}
                component={RestaurantCard}
                onSelect={selectRestaurant}
            >
                {" "}
            </RestaurantList>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CustomerDash;
```

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

As Abu mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70024149/), you need to call `setRestaurants`, not `this.setRestaurants`. Also, since you are using `async/await` syntax, you don't need all of those `.then()` calls.

```js
const fetchList = async (id) => {
  const response = await fetch(`/restaurant/id/${id}`).catch((err) => throw err);
  const json = await response.json();
  setRestaurants(json);
  console.log(restaurants);
  return true;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's functional component so use **setRestaurants** instead of **this.setRestaurants**

```
const fetchList = async (id) => {
    try {
        const resp = await fetch("/restaurant/id/" + id)
            .then((resp) => resp.json())
            .then(data => 
            setRestaurants(data))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
    }
    catch (err) {
        throw err;
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

After updating state, you won't get state value instantly. so your **console.log(restaurants)** won't work.

Comment: I made the change but now my page wont render at all and I get the error "TypeError: itemList.map is not a function" for the component that renders the Restaurant List Component. 


```import React from "react";
const RestaurantList = ({ itemList, component, onSelect }) => {
  const Component = component;

  return (
    <div className="list2">
      <h1>Restaurants</h1>
      {itemList.map((item) => (
        <Component key={item._Restaurant__id} item={item} onSelect={onSelect} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default RestaurantList;
```